# Mocking out parameters with JustMock

Tags: c#, mocking, justmock

I am writing unit tests and I need to mock the out parameter of the one of the target method dependencies with the following signature:

```
bool TryProcessRequest(out string)
```

I am using **JustMock** and I have tried to use `DoInstead` arrangement clause, but it seems that it is not so obvious.

Please advise me how to achieve this, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option will probably suit you:

```
var mock = Mock.Create<IYourInterface>(); 
string expectedResult = "result"; 
Mock.Arrange(() => mock.TryProcessRequest(out expectedResult)).Returns(true); 

string actualResult; 
bool isCallSuccessful = mock.TryProcessRequest(out actualResult);
```

So for this you need to create a local variable with the desired value and use that in the out position.